# Downloading with Python+PhantomJS by emulating a click

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to write a script which downloads a zip file from a website, but the file is served with a javascript call and not with a known URL, so I'm trying to emulate a click over the element to download the file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from selenium import webdriver


meff_data_download_url = "http://www.meff.com/aspx/DerEnergia/DescargaFicheros.aspx?id=esp"
zip_file_javascript_call = "sacaVentana('/docs/Ficheros/Descarga/dME/ME170523.zip')"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(meff_data_download_url)        
    browser.find_elements_by_class_name('zip')[0].click()
```

The program script ends without errors, but no file is downloaded. I saw examples in other SO questions and they did not do any other additional thing to actually store the downloaded file, which seems strange, but I don't known if that's the problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. You just need to swap out the file location to where your phantomJS executable file is located. You can also modify the file location where you store the downloaded files on the last line:

```
def Download_PDF():
    phantomJSdriver = r'C:\Program Files\PhantomJS\bin\phantomjs.exe'
    meff_data_download_url = "http://www.meff.com/aspx/DerEnergia/DescargaFicheros.aspx?id=esp"
    main_link = "http://www.meff.com"

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomJSdriver) # webdriver.PhantomJS() if not Windows

    driver.get(meff_data_download_url)

    links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='/docs/Ficheros/Descarga/dME']")

    thelinks = [main_link + str(link.get_attribute('href')).split("javascript:sacaVentana('")[1].split("')")[0]
                for link in links]

    for i in range(0, len(thelinks)):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(thelinks[i], str(i)+'.zip')
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PhantomJS does not support downloads.  Here is the tracking ticket on their side for the feature: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052

You can try using the new headless version of chrome, should work nicely with your current implementation.
https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/

Alternatively, you can use PhantomJS to grab what you need, when you have the element, extract the href out, and use python-requests or urllib to retrieve the file.